# Google Maps and writing down adresses in DB

Tags: google-maps, symfony, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am quite new to Symfony 2 and I am looking for solution to following issue. I am using Symfony 2.8.
I have to add a feature to my application, that renders on main page a Google Map and renders events stored in my database on this map (of course Event entity has a column 'adress'). Now I am not sure what I should use? I suppose I have to take one bundle integrating Google Maps with symfony and another one for geocoding an adress (translate adress into to two columns refering to longitude and latitude and to render translating it back form DB to adress)? Am I right? 
I have read about these bundles:
https://github.com/egeloen/ivory-google-map 
This one seems to be most popular, but they say it throws a lot of errors and many things are deprecated for Symfony 2...

or this one
https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/installation.md
and some others like BazingaGeocoderBundle and so on.

Which do you advice? What should be next steps of implementation it to my project? 
Do i need deep knowledge about JavaScript?

Another feature of Google Maps on my site should be adding User participation (I have also entity User connected with FOSUser Bundle) in Event directly on map, while rendering little message over the event on map. How to deal with it? Is it javascript?

Maybe should I use plain Google-Maps-API? Where and how I should start if this is the best solution.

Of course if any files are needed I will provide it at order.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, eventually I have used two Google's APIs - Google Maps Geocoding API and Google Maps JavaScript API. Statci API wouldn't be enough to make it work.

Majority of bundles for geocoding or google maps for symfony dont't work properly or have poor documentation. What is more I think it is easier to upgrade escpecially part touching google map, when whole code is in java script.

The easiest method for fixing it is using examples from google maps documentation: [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/) and mofify them according to your own needs. This way I has added markers signing events from my db (also ajax is useful) and custom searchbox, iterating through all of these marakers.

In case of geocoding I prepared a script triggerd while pushing submit button and it creates hidden input in form with coords of address given by user using the form.

If someone needs any part of code for similar task, please write me a message and I will provide it here.

Comment: Hello @lord_of_strings
Can you share your code please?
Thanks in advanced